# Could someone clarify why if I use one variable its wrong but if I change it to another I get the right solution?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I am solving this code challenge:
Create a function `countBy` that accepts an array and a callback, and returns an object. `countBy` will iterate through the array and performs the callback on each element. Each return value from the callback will be saved as a key on the object. The value associated with each key will be the number of times that particular return value was returned.

Below is the code I did

```
    function countBy(array, callback){
        let newObj = {}
      let numOdd = 0
      let numEv = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        let callbackRes = callback(array[i])
        if(callback(array[i]) === 'even'){
          numEv++
        }
        else if(callback(array[i]) === 'odd'){
          numOdd++
        }
        newObj[callbackRes] = numOdd
      }
        return newObj
    }
```

I got the right solution which is:

{ odd: 3, even: 2 }

However, I'm not quite sure why that is? At first, I was trying to set

```
        newObj[callbackRes] = numEv, numOdd
```

However, that gave me this solution:

```
{ odd: 2, even: 2 }
```

and I figured out that trying to assign the object to both values just assigns it to the first var.

Why does setting the obj value to `numOdd` return a different value than numEv? Shouldn't it be the same since it's going through the same for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the statement of the code challenge, the solution in javascript would be the following:

```
function countBy(array, callback) {
  let newObj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let callbackRes = callback(array[i]);
    if (newObj[callbackRes] === undefined) {
      newObj[callbackRes] = 1;
    }
    else newObj[callbackRes]++;
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this Javascript?  You never mention that.  In Javascript, the comma operator separates expressions.  Your statement would have been interpreted as:

```
(newObj[callbackRes] = numEv) , numOdd
```

So it assigns the first value, then the second value is just discarded.

Comment: hi thank you for answering. It is in javascript i should have clarified. I figured out by messing with the nums array that my code wasnt even correct I just got lucky that it returned the right solution. After thinking more I came up with the right solution.

Comment: `function countBy(array, callback){
 let newObj = {}
  let numOdd = 0
  let numEv = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    let callbackRes = callback(array[i])
    newObj[callbackRes] = null
    if(callback(array[i]) === 'even'){
      numEv++
      newObj.even = numEv
      
    }
    else if(callback(array[i]) === 'odd'){
      numOdd++
      newObj.odd = numOdd
    }
  }
 return newObj
}`  this is correct, sorry Ive never really used stack overflow before